# Biopython: Getting XML-file by Protein accession

Tags: xml, biopython

I have a file full of Uniprot IDs.
Now I'm looking for a way to download the entire XML-entry for each of the IDs.

Comment: What have you tried ? Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will allow us to better help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you build a URL for each UniProt ID to retrieve the XML definition for a protein.

```py
uniprot_id = 'P12345'
url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/'+uniprot_id+'.xml'
```

You can construct URLs to retrieve different data formats by changing the end of the string i.e. '.txt, .fasta, .rdf'. This [link](http://www.uniprot.org/help/programmatic_access) gives more specific details on uniprot access patterns.

Next you open the url and parse the output using BioPython. Alternatively, you could save the XML string to disk.

```py
import urllib2
from Bio import SeqIO

uniprot_id = 'P12345'
url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/'+uniprot_id+'.xml'
s = urllib2.urlopen(url)
contents = s.read()

record = SeqIO.read(contents, 'uniprot-xml')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I discovered that I could actually just upload the textfile on Uniprot and download all results in xml-format. Sometimes the answer is just too easy to think of it right away.